# Maximum Entropy classifier for big data sets

Tags: nlp, machine-learning, classification

I have been looking for a maximum entropy classification implementation which can deal with an output size of 500 classes and 1000 features. My training data has around 30,000,000 lines.
I have tried using MegaM, the 64-bit R maxent package, the maxent tool from the University of Edinburgh but as expected, none of them can handle the size of data. However, the size of the data set doesn't seem too out of the world for nlp tasks of this nature. 
Are there any techniques that I should be employing? Or any suggestion for a toolkit which I may use?
I am trying to run this on a 64-bit Windows machine with 8GB of RAM,using Cygwin where required.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Vowpal Wabbit](http://hunch.net/~vw/) is currently regarded as the fastest large-scale learner. [LibLinear](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) is an alternative, but I'm not sure if it can handle matrices of 3e10 elements.

Note that the term "MaxEnt" is used almost exclusively by NLP people; machine learning folks call it logistic regression or logit, so if you search for that you might find many more tools than when you search for MaxEnt.

Comment: Can Vowpal Wabbit deal with multiclass classification? All examples I see on their page deals with binary classification.

Comment: @atlantis: according to [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/26211/8517) it can, but the functionality is not well-documented. Its [wiki](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Input-format), however, states that labels should be 1 or -1 for logistic loss, so you may have to do one-vs.-all training.

Comment: Liblinear also essentially does one-vs-the-rest training for logistic regression. But it does that out of the box. Seems to be working fine with my data set so far. Will edit if I see any issues.